# How to loop into folders that contains specific file extensions?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I want to merge splited audio files in sub folder with `Sox`. I have this basic script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Example: sox_merge_subfolder.sh input_dir/ output_dir/

# Soure directory with subfolder that contains splitted mp3
input_dir=$1

# Set the directory you want for the merged mp3s
output_dir=$2

# make sure the output directory exists (create it if not)
mkdir -p "$output_dir"

find "$input_dir" -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
  echo "Processing..."
  cd "$file"
  output_file="$output_dir/${PWD##*/} - Track only.mp3"
  echo "  Output: $output_file"
  sox --show-progress *.mp3 "$output_file"
done
```

It is working but I would like to switch to a command that use only folders that contains `mp3`. To avoid error like `sox FAIL formats: can't open input file '*.mp3': No such file or directory`

I have this command that work `find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.mp3" -exec dirname {} \; | uniq`. But the path are relative and I fail to include it into my existing script.

Answer (score 2):

We can still use `find` to find all directories, but the loop that takes those directories will have to test for MP3 files:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

indir=$1
outdir=$2

mkdir -p "$outdir" || exit 1

find "$indir" -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -c '
    outdir=$1; shift

    for dirpath do
        mp3files=( "$dirpath"/*.mp3 )
        [[ ${#mp3files[@]} -eq 0 ]] && continue

        printf -v outfile "%s - Track only.mp3" "${dirpath##*/}"

        sox --show-progress "${mp3files[@]}" "$outdir/$outfile"
    done' bash "$outdir" {} +
```

This `/bin/sh` script runs `find` and `find` runs a short in-line `bash` script.  The `bash` script will be called with batches of pathnames to directories, but the first argument will be the pathname of the output directory.  This is received in `outdir` in the `bash` script, and that argument is shifted off the list of positional parameters, leaving only a list of directory pathnames.

The in-line script then iterates over these directories, and expands tho glob `*.mp3` in each, yielding a list of pathnames for MP3 files that we store in the `mp3files` array.

Since we use `-O nullglob` for this script, the array will be empty if there are no matching filenames, so the `-eq 0` test is used to skip to the next iteration if this is the case.

We then construct the output filename from the current directory pathname, and run the `sox` command on the collected MP3 filenames.

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 1):

This does the `cd` in a subshell

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

input_dir=$1
output_dir=$2

mkdir -p "$output_dir"

while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
  files=("$dir"/*.mp3)
  if (( ${#files[*]} )); then
    ( 
     cd "$dir" || exit
     output_file=$output_dir/${PWD##*/}
     echo " Output: $output_file"
     echo sox --show-progress "${files[@]##*/} "$output_file"
    )
  fi 
done < <(find "$input_dir" -type d -print0)
```

- Remove the `echo` before the `sox` If you think the output is correct.
- I have never used `sox` before just so you know.